# Would removing features from our mvp just because competitors are doing it better be reasonable decision?

Tags: features, competitive-analysis, mvp

Two of our three core features are already developed by tech giants and there is no value we can provide beyond what the competitors are offering. Would removing them just because competitors are doing it better be a reasonable solution? If so, how could I communicate this decision to the team?

Comment: A reasonable solution to what? Are the features not being used? What made you implement them in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

My sense is that your stakeholders probably already know that tech giants are doing a great job at these features, but they want to do it anyway. There were plenty of search engines doing a competent job before Google came along, and lots of design software came before Figma.

The question you're probably going to need to help everyone understand is, why would your customers choose your solution? You say there is "absolutely no value" you can provide - are you 100% sure?

I think there are a few things you can do at this stage:

1. Research customer pain points as they use the status quo. Everyone used Microsoft Word. How did Google Docs get into the market? They saw what a pain it was to use Word to collaborate with others, and focused on that feature. What can your app do better than the status quo? You might conduct some user interviews and focus groups.
2. Do market research. What would get your target audience to not use the big tech solutions, and use yours? Cost? Privacy? Integration support? Figma realized that not everybody could afford an Adobe XD license, and created a freemium product that dominated the market.
3. Create some early prototypes and gather feedback. If you are truly reinventing the wheel and users signal that they're not likely to move off their existing platforms because they don't see the value in your product - that's the data you'd give to your team. And then let them make a decision about it. It might not be "kill the new features", it might be "buy access to and integrate existing features".